# Django - dynamic form from Model with choices

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to implement dynamic form which displays a few option from database's choices. The form should display names of CASES (i.e. "Option 1") for given lawyer_id.

For example: user selects lawyer with ID = 6 and this lawyer_id has "Option 1" and "Option 2" in LawyersSpec model. In the form I want to display only "Option 1" and "Option 2" as possible options. How can I achieve that?

I have tried dynamic forms with overriding the queryset in *init*

```py
    def __init__(self, *args, lawyer_id, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        lawyer_spec = LawyersSpec.objects.filter(lawyer_id=lawyer_id)
```

but it returns the whole name of the record from the database, not only the choice value.

**models.py**

```py
class LawyersSpec(models.Model):
    lawyer_id = models.ForeignKey('MyUser', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    lawyer_spec = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=CASES)

CASES = (
    (1, 'Option 1'),
    (2, 'Option 2'),
    (3, 'Option 3'),
    (4, 'Option 4'),
    )
```

EDIT:
I just want to display in spec field options ("Option 1", "Option 2" ...) which are available for given lawyer_id.

**forms.py**

```py
class MakeAppointmentForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    spec = forms.ChoiceField()
```

Comment: If the form field is a `ChoiceField`, just initialise is with `choices=...` where you put in the list of tuples, e.g. based on `LawyersSpec.objects.filter(lawyer_id=lawyer_id).values('lawyer_spec')`.

Comment: But since you're not showing the form or what values you're going to save with it (which is not the same as what you display, hence a list of tuples for `choices`) it's hard to be more specific in our answer.

Comment: I have added forms.py, basically I want to display exactly what is in CASES values ("Option 1" etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your init method for the form, reset the `spec` field's choices:

```
# after super().__init__
lawyer_specs = LawyersSpec.objects.filter(lawyer_id=lawyer_id)
choices = ((spec.lawyer_spec, dict(CASES)[spec.lawyer_spec]) for spec in lawyer_specs)
self.fields['spec'].choices = choices
```

Don't forget to import `CASES` from your models. It would be easier to have `CASES` inside the `LawyerSpec` class, then you can just refer to `LawyerSpec.CASES`

Comment: Thank tou! It worked, but now I have problem with saving the form - it's always invalid. How to save selected _spec_ in the form?

Comment: Thing is, you've shown a `Form`, which doesn't have a `save()`, so what are you saving? So maybe open a new question and show us your full code.

Comment: There are no errors, the form is invalid, because the field spec is empty

Comment: if form.is_valid() is False, then form.errors is not empty. There are always form errors in that case. You should always show them in your template `{{ form.errors }}`. You probably mean there are no server errors, which is correct (status 200), your server just renders the form with errors in your template.

Comment: In my template I have {{ form.errors }} and {{ form.non_field_errors }} but it's doesn't show anything

Comment: so how do you know field spec is empty is the cause for the form being not valid?

Comment: you should open a new question showing your view code and your form code. Again you're talking about saving a form, but in the code you've shown here you can't save the form (your `MakeAppointmentForm` does not have a save method), you're saying the form is not valid but you're not showing how you instantiate it nor how you display it in your template. We need the code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Later I get error that I'm trying to save data to database "null value in column "lawyer_spec" violates not-null constraint". I'll make new ticket in a moment.

Comment: For that error we need to know which model you're trying to save. I suspect you're doing the wrong thing entirely. If you're trying to save a fk to LawyersSpec, you shouldn't have a ChoiceField but a ModelChoiceField.

Comment: Link to new ticket https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57711611/django-empty-form-cannot-be-saved-in-database