# Django - empty form cannot be saved in database

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a form in which, user specifies *lawyer-spec* and save the data to the database. However I get an error that

```
**null value in column "lawyer_spec" violates not-null constraint**
```

So the data from the form is not processed properly.

EDIT:

mthod `form_invalid` prints empty line, and then two numbers ('pk' and 'lawyer_id')

**forms.py**

```py
class MakeAppointmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CalendarAppointmentsReserved
        fields = ['case']

    def __init__(self, *args, lawyer_id, pk, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        lawyer_id_from_kwargs = lawyer_id
        lawyer_specs = LawyersSpec.objects.filter(lawyer=lawyer_id_from_kwargs)

        choices = [(spec.lawyer_spec, dict(CASES)[spec.lawyer_spec]) for spec in lawyer_specs]

        self.fields['case'].choices = choices
```

**views.py**

```py
@method_decorator(user_required, name='dispatch')
class MakingAppointmentView(CreateView):
    template_name = "make_appointment.html"
    form_class = TestPy.forms.MakeAppointmentForm
    model = TestPy.models.CalendarAppointmentsReserved

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        self.kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()

        self.kwargs = {'lawyer_id': self.request.session['lawyer_id'], 'pk': pk}

        self.kwargs.update(self.kwargs)  # self.kwargs contains all url conf params
        return self.kwargs


    def form_invalid(self, form):
        print(form.errors)
        print(self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        print(self.kwargs.get('lawyer_id'))
        return redirect('home')


    def form_valid(self, form):
        calendar_model = TestPy.models.CalendarFreeSlot.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        calendar_model.is_available = False
        calendar_model.save()

        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.users_id = self.request.user
        self.object.calendar_free_id = calendar_model
        self.request.session['free_calendar_id'] = calendar_model.pk
        self.request.session['lawyer_id'] = calendar_model.lawyer_id.pk

        self.object.save()
        return redirect('home')
```

**models.py**

```py
class LawyersSpec(models.Model):
    lawyer = models.ForeignKey('MyUser', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    lawyer_spec = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=CASES)

class CalendarAppointmentsReserved(models.Model):
    calendar_free_id = models.ForeignKey('CalendarFreeSlot', on_delete=models.PROTECT) 
    users_id = models.ForeignKey('MyUser', on_delete=models.PROTECT) 
    case = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=CASES)
```

How can I process the data properly and save in the database?

Comment: look at the logic in your get_form_kwargs() method. that can't work.

Comment: Why? What's the problem? If I put `self.kwargs.get` after `super()` it doesn't have 'pk' value

Comment: self.kwargs = super() and in the next line self.kwargs = {..}. Same as writing `a = 1; a = 2`. What do you think the value of `a` is?

Comment: Last question, how can I bound the form? Because I have read that my problem is unbound form, but I don't know to bound it, while it's dynamically generated?

Comment: it's bound when form.data is not None, which happens when you pass it data. In your code above, you remove all the form kwargs that it would get via super().get_form_kwargs() which include the data, that's why your form didn't get bound. Just fix that part of the code and your form will be bound.

Comment: It is working. Thank you very much for your help and your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a crucial mistake here:

- Your `CreateView` is for a `CalendarAppointmentsReserved` model
- Your form is for a `LawyersSpec` model

That's not possible, because the create view for model `A` is expecting a `ModelForm` for the same model `A`.

Change your form to this:

```
class MakeAppointmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CalendarAppointmentsReserved
        fields = ['case']

    def __init__(self, *args, lawyer_id, pk, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        lawyer_specs = LawyersSpec.objects.filter(lawyer=lawyer_id)
        choices = [(spec.lawyer_spec, dict(CASES)[spec.lawyer_spec]) for spec in lawyer_specs]
        self.fields['case'].choices = choices
```

Now in your view you don't need to assign `self.object.case` anymore.

You're also resetting `self.kwargs` in your `get_form_kwargs()` method by assigning it a dictionary directly. And then `self.kwargs.update(self.kwargs)` does nothing, you're updating a dict with itself. So you loose all the POST data here. The proper way to do it is like this:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    form_kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()  # don't mess up self.kwargs
    pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
    form_kwargs.update({'lawyer_id': self.request.session['lawyer_id'], 'pk': pk})
    return form_kwargs
```

Comment: I've changed that and now the error says **null value in column "case" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (29, null, 21, 3).**

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint in your form_valid() method and inspect form.cleaned_data and self.request.POST? (or print them if you don't know how to set a breakpoint, but I'd advise you to learn that quickly as it'll make your life so much easier)

Comment: And you did remove the line `self.object.case = self.object.spec`?

Comment: I have removed `self.object.case = self.object.spec`

Comment: and? what's self.request.POST?

Comment: The problem is that this form is still invalid. I get those messages from form_invalid method

Comment: case  '2'

first_name  'As'

Comment: How can you get an error saving an object if the form is invalid? you only save in the form_valid method don't you?

Comment: then look at form.errors in your form_invalid method, what's the error making the form invalid?

Comment: In form_invalid method `print(form.errors)` prints only empty line

Comment: ok, please update your question showing the **entire** form code and the **entire** view code. There must be some code in there that I don't know of, because with just the code you're showing it's impossible.

Comment: Note that your question was answered (the reason you got the null-constraint violation error on 'layers_spec' initially).